# How do I use IfStrEqCase within a siunitx command?

Tags: errors, siunitx, xstring

I am having trouble using `\IfStrEqCase` from [xstring](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) inside `\num` from [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\bla}[1]{%
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{a}{1}%
    {b}{2}%
    {c}{3}}%
    [0]%
}
\newcommand{\blubb}[1]{1}

\begin{document}
|\num{\blubb{a}}|
|\bla{a}|
|\num{\bla{a}}|    
\end{document}
```

Will fail at `|\num{\bla{a}}|` with:

```
pdflatex.exe> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
pdflatex.exe> \reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a 
pdflatex.exe>                                *{\let \@xs@assign\@xs@expand@and@detokenize...
pdflatex.exe> l.16 |\num{\bla{a}}
pdflatex.exe>                    |
pdflatex.exe> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I overcome this? Solutions that do not include `IfStrEqCase` but provide some other way to do `switch`/`case` are welcome.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve as an outcome? The `\num` command is meant to format 'numbers', not really 'expressions' and certainly not things that can't be expanded to numbers. You input (_e.g._ `a`) doesn't look at all like a number!

Comment: @JosephWright I am going to have the definition of \bla outsourced in an included .tex file that is automatically generated by a script in a programming language of my choice thay expands the `IfStrEqCase` command with all variables (eg. a,b,c) with its values(1,2,3) and an other hopfully and other `IfStrEqCase` with their units... (I know sweave and knitr, but working with invalid `latex` code is no option with my editor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the manual says, commands from `xstring` are not fully expandable and may not be nested nor used e.g. in `\edef`.  Several of the `xstring` commands thus have a final optional argument which is a macro where the result may be stored.  This in to the situation for `\IfStrEqCase`, so you need to provide something like this in the code for each case.  For example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\bla}[2]{%
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{a}{\xdef#2{1}}%
    {b}{\xdef#2{2}}%
    {c}{\xdef#2{3}}}%
    [\xdef#2{0}]%
}
\newcommand{\blubb}[1]{1}

\begin{document}
|\num{\blubb{a}}|

|\bla{a}{\outp}\outp|

|\bla{b}{\outp}\num{\outp}|    
\end{document}
```

In this way you can define a command

```
\newcommand{\blanum}[1]{\bla{#1}{\outp}\num{\outp}}
```

that you can use directly as `\blanum{b}`.

Comment: Works like a charm, ty! I would appreciate if extended your answer for a shortcut à la `\newcommand{\bla}[1]{\blahelper{#1}{\outp}\num{\outp}}` to make clear it is almost as easy to use as if `\IfStrEqCase` was fully expandable (whatever that means).

Comment: OK, example definition added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `stringstrings`.  While the `\convertchar` macro cannot be nested inside of a `\num` argument, its result (`\thestring`) is expandable, and can thus be solved in a two-step, as I do in the macro `\Inum` (indirect `\num`).

EDITED to take not just letters, but words, as arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\Inum[1]{\bla[q]{#1}\num{\thestring}}

\newcommand{\bla}[2][v]{%
    \convertword[q]{#2}{ax}{1}%
    \convertword[q]{\thestring}{by}{2}%
    \convertword[#1]{\thestring}{c}{3}%
}
\newcommand{\blubb}[1]{1}

\begin{document}
|\num{\blubb{a}}|
|\bla{ax}|
|\Inum{by}|  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok. But it only works for single chars (I admit, I did not state this requirement in the question). And what is that q as first argument of `bla` needed for? Anyway good answer explaining this \thestring trick.

Comment: @YAK  Fixed for your revised case, merely by changing `\convertchar` into `\convertword`.  The `[q]` option is for "quiet", so that intermediate results (stored in `\thestring`) are not printed out.  I made the default `[v]` verbose, so that `\thestring` is printed out at the end of `\bla`, unless invoked with a `[q]` (or a `[e]`, see package documentation for details).

Comment: thank you for the fix and the explanation, works like a charm.