# \IfEqCase not working inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I'm working on the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\swcase}[1]{
    \IfEqCase{#1}{{a}{1}{b}{2}}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    single/.style={draw,circle}
    ]
    \draw node[single,fill=white] at (6,\swcase{a}) {\swcase{a}};
    %\draw node[single,fill=white] at (6,1) {\swcase{a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code fails to compile with `pdflatex`, and I get the following error message:

```
! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 ... node[single,fill=white] at (6,\swcase{a})
                                                   {\swcase{a}};
```

The macro `\swcase` should return `1` when fed with the argument `a`. You can confirm this by commenting the failing line and uncommenting the one below, where the macro inside the coordinates is substituted with the expected result. The example works as expected and draws a circle with the text `1` (resulting from the macro `\swcase`) in it.
Why is it not working if I embed the `\swcase` macro inside the coordinate vector?

By the way, it doesn't make any difference if I put the `\IfEqCase` statement directly into the coordinate parenthesis instead of using the wrapper macro.

Comment: No problem with TikZ: before your `tikzpicture`, try `\edef\myvalue{\swcase{a}}`...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164921/14500

Comment: @PaulGaborit No, I wouldn't say it's a duplicate of that one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the coordinate argument you need something that expands to a number, but `\IfEqCase` expands to a series of instructions to *print* one.

Use an expandable string switch macro, for instance `\str_case:nn` provided by `expl3` (and here loaded by `xparse`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\swcase}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {a}{1}
    {b}{2}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    single/.style={draw,circle}
    ]
    \draw node[single,fill=white] at (6,\swcase{a}) {\swcase{a}};
    \draw node[single,fill=white] at (6,\swcase{b}) {\swcase{b}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The syntax is not really different from `\IfEqCase`, as you see.

[image]

If you need it in a `\foreach` loop, use the “expanded” version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\swcase}{m}
 {
  \str_case_e:nn { #1 }
   {
    {a}{1}
    {b}{2}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[single/.style={draw,circle}]
\foreach \i in {a,b} {
  \draw node[single,fill=white] at (6,\swcase{\i}) {\swcase{\i}};
  \draw node[single,fill=white] at (6,\swcase{\i}) {\swcase{\i}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but if I embed the `\draw` command inside an `\foreach` loop, the `\swcase` macro seems to not yield any result: `\foreach \i in {a,b}
        \draw node[single,fill=white] at (6,\swcase{\i}) {\swcase{\i}};`The circles are just drawn above each other at coordinate 0 and the text is missing.

Comment: @JoeZocker The fix is easy, done. You can use the `\str_case_x:nn` function also in the previous case, of course.

Comment: What about if I need to use multiple conditions/variables for the same case, for example CASE1: if a=1 and /orb=2 : then do this and so on.Identifying multiple variables in the same case

Comment: @Silva I believe a new question with the details is in order.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529341/multiple-cases-for-xstring-package